# Hosting wcf service in WAS

Tags: wcf, windows-vista, was

I wrote my WCF Service I need to host this in Windows Activation services (WAS) in my vista machine..

Please tell how to host my service in WAS..

Also how to consume this client apps

Answer (score 1):

See [Configuring WAS for TCP Endpoints](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-Screencast-Configuring-WAS-for-TCP-Endpoints/) and the other resources at the [WCF Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/wcf/) on MSDN.